# Need help figuring out how to exclude selecting an element if it has text in it

Tags: jquery

I would like to select and element with a class called "validate_me", but I don't want to include any elements if they have text already inside them, but I'm stuck on the jquery.  It looks like ":contains()" could do the trick but I don't want to search for a particular string, I just want to "exclude" any element that already has text in it.

I hope this makes sense...How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Here's what I attempted before, but it obviously doesn't work:

```
$("input.validate_me:not(:contains('any text is allowed')),select").addClass("ui-state-error");
```

Comment: You mean inputs with an empty `value` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input.validate_me').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == ""; }).addClass("ui-state-error");
```

Comment: Where does it selects the `select` element?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Wroking **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y2XBv/1/)**

```
$(function(){
    $("input.validate_me").filter(function(){
        return !$(this).val();
    }).add("select").addClass("ui-state-error"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').each(function() {

    if ($(this).val() != '') {

        $(this).addClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Anank/

Answer (score 0):

and for the sake of more than one solution, you can always put your undesired nodes in an array and pass that to the .not() method

http://jsfiddle.net/SNXzU/

```
var nodeArray = [];
var nodeList = $("input.validate_me");

for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++ )
    if ($("input.validate_me")[i].value.length > 0)
        nodeArray.push($("input.validate_me")[i]);

nodeList.not(nodeArray).addClass("ui-state-error");
```